# Image downloading via multithreading not working in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have to download an image from a url and then show the downloaded image in a imageview on the UI. 
For this i am using the code mentioned below:

```
public class ShowUIData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String productvalues[];
    Drawable productimagebitmap;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        productvalues = hb.getProductDetailsWithJson(id + 1);
        if (productvalues != null) {
            productimagebitmap = getImage(productvalues[3]);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (productvalues != null) {
            // Set the values obtained from the database.
            // Check if image returned from URL is not null.
            if (productimagebitmap != null) {
                ImageView productimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.productimage);
                productimage.setImageDrawable(productimagebitmap);
            }
        }
        dismissDialog();
    }

    // Download image from URL obtained for database.
    private Drawable getImage(String address) {
        try {
            Log.i("product details", "starting image download");
            URL url = new URL(address);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            is.close();
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("the url", address);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.noimage);
        }
    }
```

A valid URL is being passed to the getImage function and no exception is being thrown , still the image is not being set on the imageview. When i debug my application, then the image is setting properly.
I believe i need to put a blocking call until the image is download and then call image.setImageDrawable.

What is the problem occuring over here. I am not able to figure out why i am not able to load any images and why only when i debug , i see an image?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try [this](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/archives/master) example. It runtime fetches images from the url and also displays it in listview. I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Non UI thread can't update UI component. Use handler to update UI component.

Comment: onPostExecute is executed on the UI thread. so i am not doing anything out of the UI thread.